# PySpark generate missing dates and fill data with previous value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cross-join

I need help for this case to fill, with a new row, missing values:

This is just an example, but I have a lot of rows with different `IDs`.

**Input dataframe**:

| ID | FLAG | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| 123 | 0 | 01/02/2021 |
| 123 | 1 | 01/03/2021 |
| 123 | 0 | 01/06/2021 |
| 123 | 0 | 01/08/2021 |
| 777 | 0 | 01/01/2021 |
| 777 | 1 | 01/03/2021 |

So I have a finite set of `dates` and I wanna take until the last one for each `ID` (in the example, for `ID = 123`: 01/01/2021, 01/02/2021, 01/03/2021... until 01/08/2021). So basically I could do a cross join with a calendar, but I don't know how can I fill missing value with a rule or a filter, after the cross join.

**Expected output**: (in bold the generated missing values)

| ID | FLAG | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| 123 | 0 | 01/02/2021 |
| 123 | 1 | 01/03/2021 |
| **123** | **1** | **01/04/2021** |
| **123** | **1** | **01/05/2021** |
| 123 | 0 | 01/06/2021 |
| **123** | **0** | **01/07/2021** |
| 123 | 0 | 01/08/2021 |
| 777 | 0 | 01/01/2021 |
| **777** | **0** | **01/02/2021** |
| 777 | 1 | 01/03/2021 |

Comment: Can you eloborate on the logic behind the date for the new row being `04/04/2021` for new row created after `03/03/2021`? Also is the dates a finite set? (01/01/2021, 02/02/2021, 03/04/2021 .... 11/11/2021, 12/12/2021)?

Comment: yes, I wrote these dates to give an example ... but I have all the months with the first day of the month (I rectified it)... so i have a finite set of elements and i wanna take until the last one for that ID (in the example, for ID 123: 01/01/2021, 01/02/2021, 01/03/2021... until 01/08/2021). So basically i could do a cross join with a calendar, but i don't know how can i fill missing value with a rule or a filter, after the crossjoin.

Answer (score 12):

You can first group by `id` to calculate max and min `date` then using [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#sequence) function, generate all the dates from `min_date` to `max_date`. Finally, join with original dataframe and fill nulls with last non null per group of `id`. Here's a complete working example:

Your input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (123, 1, "01/01/2021"), (123, 0, "01/02/2021"),
    (123, 1, "01/03/2021"), (123, 0, "01/06/2021"),
    (123, 0, "01/08/2021"), (777, 0, "01/01/2021"),
    (777, 1, "01/03/2021")
], ["id", "flag", "date"])
```

Groupby `id` and generate all possible dates for each `id`:

```
all_dates_df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.date_trunc("mm", F.max(F.to_date("date", "dd/MM/yyyy"))).alias("max_date"),
    F.date_trunc("mm", F.min(F.to_date("date", "dd/MM/yyyy"))).alias("min_date")
).select(
    "id",
    F.expr("sequence(min_date, max_date, interval 1 month)").alias("date")
).withColumn(
    "date", F.explode("date")
).withColumn(
    "date",
    F.date_format("date", "dd/MM/yyyy")
)
```

Now, left join with `df` and use [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.last.html) function over a Window partitioned by `id` to fill null values:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")

result = all_dates_df.join(df, ["id", "date"], "left").select(
    "id",
    "date",
    *[F.last(F.col(c), ignorenulls=True).over(w).alias(c)
      for c in df.columns if c not in ("id", "date")
     ]
)

result.show()
#+---+----------+----+
#| id|      date|flag|
#+---+----------+----+
#|123|01/01/2021|   1|
#|123|01/02/2021|   0|
#|123|01/03/2021|   1|
#|123|01/04/2021|   1|
#|123|01/05/2021|   1|
#|123|01/06/2021|   0|
#|123|01/07/2021|   0|
#|123|01/08/2021|   0|
#|777|01/01/2021|   0|
#|777|01/02/2021|   0|
#|777|01/03/2021|   1|
#+---+----------+----+
```

Comment: This is amazing!! How did I not think about it... maybe I didn't know the "last" function! :) 
Just a curiosity: 
just a curiosity: how could I paste the entire previous row instead of just the "flag" field? (in case I also have other variables).
Thank you very much, you were so precious! Merry Christmas!

Comment: can u write the entire code row please?

Answer (score 5):

You can find the ranges of dates between the `DATE` value in the current row and the following row and then use [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html) to generate all intermediate dates and explode this  array to fill in values for the missing dates.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [(123, 1, "01/01/2021",),
        (123, 0, "01/02/2021",),
        (123, 1, "01/03/2021",),
        (123, 0, "01/06/2021",),
        (123, 0, "01/08/2021",),
        (777, 0, "01/01/2021",),
        (777, 1, "01/03/2021",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ID", "FLAG", "DATE",)).withColumn("DATE", F.to_date(F.col("DATE"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("DATE")

next_date = F.coalesce(F.lead("DATE", 1).over(window_spec), F.col("DATE") + F.expr("interval 1 month"))

end_date_range = next_date - F.expr("interval 1 month")


df.withColumn("Ranges", F.sequence(F.col("DATE"), end_date_range, F.expr("interval 1 month")))\
  .withColumn("DATE", F.explode("Ranges"))\
  .withColumn("DATE", F.date_format("date", "dd/MM/yyyy"))\
  .drop("Ranges").show(truncate=False)
```

### Output

```
+---+----+----------+
|ID |FLAG|DATE      |
+---+----+----------+
|123|1   |01/01/2021|
|123|0   |01/02/2021|
|123|1   |01/03/2021|
|123|1   |01/04/2021|
|123|1   |01/05/2021|
|123|0   |01/06/2021|
|123|0   |01/07/2021|
|123|0   |01/08/2021|
|777|0   |01/01/2021|
|777|0   |01/02/2021|
|777|1   |01/03/2021|
+---+----+----------+
```

Comment: @blackbishop that's weird, I ran the code and copied the results I got as is, on `   Spark v3.2.0`

Comment: Thank u Nithish! I can try also your code asap! 
You have been precious!

Comment: I confirm, setting spark session timezone to `UTC` rather than `Europe/Paris` gives the correct result ;)

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me cause "add_month is deprecated"... how can i solve it?

Comment: @Jresearcher can you elaborate on the error, since [`add_months`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.add_months.html#pyspark.sql.functions.add_months) does not appear to be deprecated.

Comment: The add_months function is temporarily disallowed because it silently changes behaviour between spark 2 and spark 3. add_months(DATE'2021-02-28', 1) is '2021-03-31' in spark 2, but '2021-03-28' in spark 3. As workaround, add intervals instead, e.g. DATE'2021-02-28' + INTERVAL 1 month.

Comment: @Jresearcher edited answer to not use `add_months`. In addition the difference is behavior is only  for month end as specified [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-24-to-30)

Comment: @Jresearcher can you confirm if the small dataset in the answer can execute without error? If it does then, it would be good to check if the dates in your input are parsed correctly and also the range of dates you are dealing with.

Comment: I have extended my example to the real dataset with many rows. I also need to check the last days of the month, so: 31/01/2021, 28/02/2021 etc. The problem remains the same of the question but with the last month's dates. Thank u for ur patience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240419/discussion-between-nithish-and-jresearcher).